# Bulma: How to align list items in line for list of items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

Using Bulma css for the website .
The category list using  ul > li in list item.
Trying to get list item like the
 Image 1
[image]

My solution is not getting align porperly in center for desktop and mobile shown in
 Image 2
[image]

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
 <div class="categories">
        <h3>category</h3>
        <div class="container is-centered is-widescreen">
            <div class="content" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="columns is-desktop ">
                    <div class="column is-mobile ">
                        <h5 class="">category 1</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
                            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
                            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
                            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-mobile ">
                        <h5 class="">category 2</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
                            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
                            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
                            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-mobile ">
                        <h5 class="">category 3 </h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
                            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
                            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
                            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox (inline-flex) on the `ul` with `flex-direction: column` then re-align the text.

```css
div.content ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.content ul li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="categories">
  <h3>category</h3>
  <div class="container is-centered is-widescreen">
    <div class="content" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="columns is-desktop ">
        <div class="column is-mobile ">
          <h5 class="">category 1</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-mobile ">
          <h5 class="">category 2</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-mobile ">
          <h5 class="">category 3 </h5>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks .But it is not working has the Image1 in question.

Comment: I want the list-items to align in way as shown the Image 1.By mistake upload the wrong image.List -Items must align and justify text to center with Bullets

Comment: Edited - is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <div class="categories">
        <h3>category</h3>
        <div class="container is-centered is-widescreen">
            <div class="content" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="columns is-desktop ">
                    <div class="column is-mobile ">
                        <h5 class="">category 1</h5>
                        <ul style="list-style-type:none;text-align:center;">
                            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
                            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
                            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
                            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-mobile ">
                        <h5 class="">category 2</h5>
                        <ul style="list-style-type:none;text-align:center;">
                            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
                            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
                            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
                            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-mobile ">
                        <h5 class="">category 3 </h5>
                        <ul style="list-style-type:none;text-align:center;">
                            <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor</li>
                            <li> amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                            <li>Iusto asperiores tempora</li>
                            <li>accusamus laudantium iure</li>
                            <li> Dignissimos ab </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use css for ul tag as

```
style="display:inline-block"
```